# How to see all "Not selected" urls in Index Status of Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

Google Webmaster Tools have the menu *Health > Index Status* in which it shows:

1. Total indexed url's
2. Total not selected url's
3. Blocked url's

For the second one that is ***Not selected*** url's the reason for not selected is

> URLs from your site that redirect to other pages or URLs whose
>   contents are substantially similar to other pages

Where can we see all the not selected url's which are not indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't I'm afraid, or a least there's no Google tool that will list them for you, which I think is what you mean.

Depending on your site, it probably wouldn't be difficult to get at least an idea of which they are. Consider working through common sources of duplication first, e.g., www/non-www, http/s, parameters, use a crawling tool to get a picture of redirections within your site, etc.

Comment: However you can see the duplicate content report for pages which have substantially similar contents.

Comment: @Prasad: Where is "the duplicate content report"?